# Adding collection of eclipse projects into one netbeans projectGroup

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans-7

How to add collection of eclipse projects into one netbeans projectGroup.

If you have dir NBProjects and in it NB1, NB2, NB100 projects you can put them all into single NB project group. You can create ProjectGroup and give it path to NBProjects and it
will import all the NB1... NB100 projects into the group.

My problem is different. I have directory EclipseProjects, in it I have Eclipse projects E1, E2, .. E100.
How do I add all those projects into NB ProjectGroup.

Found a solution:
In NB.
main | File | import project | Eclipse project | specify workspace path | (now manually have to check all the boxes of the projects you want to import). 
Not too bad.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: In NB. main | File | import project | Eclipse project | specify workspace path | (now manually have to check all the boxes of the projects you want to import). Not too bad.